# Wireless Short Distance Measurement

Tags: rfid

Is is possible, and if so, is it viable, to use UHF RFID RSSI to measure distance in the 1-25 millimeter range from the RFID Reader antenna with a resolution down to below half a millimeter?

If it is, could anyone offer some hardware tips to make this work reliably?

Any insight would be appreciated, as we are concerned that the tolerances in the hardware will render this impossible.

Comment: I will be amazed if this is possible, and even more so if it's reliable.

Comment: Why do you think that RFID would be a suitable technology for your application? It wasn't designed for what you wish to do.

Comment: I don't think it would be suitable, but our design will have it anyway so we thought to investigate it.

Comment: Bubble wrap wasn't designed for its most popular application (it was designed as wallpaper), but that doesn't stop us using it where it works.  My question explores the viability of using an existing technology for a different purpose.  Maybe it is viable, maybe not.  That's what prompted me to ask the question.

Comment: I have seen a few articles and published papers that use RSSI in item location applications, but those distances are in meters, not millimeters.

Comment: I'd use a tiny (capacitive field emissions) antenna at 900MHz. For both TX and Rx.

Answer (score 2):

Someone appears to have published a thesis getting measurements on the order of 200mm here: https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/13263925/thesis_J_Huiting.pdf

So, it might be possible, but would probably earn you a degree if you pulled it off.